# Need to send a heartbeat over Modbus TCP and Read/write registers

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp

So I've got some battery management software which communicates over modbus tcp. 
I've downloaded Modbus Master (some free modbus testing software) and I've been able to successfully read and write registers BUT for the software to work it has to receive a heartbeat signal on a certain register. Cycle from 0 to 4, changing every second or something similar.

I can do it manually but then I can't read and write to other register.

How can I automate the heartbeat but leave the writing registers up to me? 
I haven't found software that could? 
How hard would it be to write a program to do this ?

I know some python and used to know C#. But very rusty in both.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let us known what is the type of device  and what did you send to it

Comment: I ended up using modbus active x control with excel from here and it working pretty well http://www.modbustools.com/modbus_activex.html